# Python SocketIO Connect

Tags: python-socketio

Please help me in creating a client instance using socketio package: socketio.AsyncClient() with details below:

import socketio

import asyncio

sio = socketio.AsyncClient(logger=False, engineio_logger=False)

I need help regarding the passing of proxy, auth, cert, etc. into above code. I went through the doc and found it below.

https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncclient-class

**http_session – an initialized requests.Session object to be used when sending requests to the server. Use it if you need to add special client options such as proxy servers, SSL certificates, etc.**

But tried many things and couldn't solve the problem, so please help if any one knows how to do it and share sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code with http_session example with proxy.

```
import socketio
import requests
session = requests.session()
#session.proxies = {'https': 'http://proxy.myproxy.com:80'}
session.proxies = {'https': 'http://user:password@proxy.myproxy.com:80'}
"""
If host is https scheme then proxies should {'https': 'proxy'}
session.proxies = {'https': 'http://proxy.myproxy.com:80'}

If host is http scheme then proxies should {'http': 'proxy'}
session.proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.myproxy.com:80'}

With username and password
session.proxies = {'http': 'user:password@http://proxy.myproxy.com:80'}
"""
cloud_socket = socketio.Client(engineio_logger=True, http_session=session)

host='https://mytestserver.io'
cloud_socket.connect(host,
                     headers={},
                     namespaces=['/api/myendpoint'],
                     transports='websocket')
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, Actually I am using socketio.AsyncClient and receiving error  "is self.http is None or self.http.closed: #pragma: no cover AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'closed'. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Also, I am executing code in link: https://docs.zerion.io/websockets/getting-started/example, just with proxy

Comment: Can you share your code and also paste full exception? My code for async client is also working.